# Do additional processing on Wordpress Username/Password prior to finalizing registration?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a use case where I need to send a POST request out to duplicate the account with an identical password and username for a parallel authentication system.

Is there a way to do this using Action Hooks? Thank you.

Comment: explain bit briefly.

Comment: I need to capture specifically the email and password and create a secondary account with matching credentials on a secondary authentication system. I need to check that account creation on the secondary system was successful before allowing completion of the Wordpress registration process. Does that make sense, I hope?

Thanks for taking the time to read.